# What is a best way to share controler with MVC Views to another project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In the asp.net core projects:

What is the best way to share a controller with MVC Views to another project?

Is it any way to build a controller with Views as a component in the assembly and share it to the different projects.

In other words how to not just simply copy code and how to reuse it to another project.

Answer (score 1):

Yes its a new feature in ASP Core called `Application Parts`.

It allows you to [store your ASP Core `Controllers/Views` etc in a separate assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/app-parts?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and then you can include/share it as `Application Parts`/Dlls which is *new in ASP Core*, the sample code from MSDN is linked above for ASP Core.

[image]

---

In the `ConfigureServices` method of your `Startup` class just add this:

```
// set this up
services.AddMvc().AddApplicationPart(assembly).AddControllersAsServices();
```

Where `assembly` is the name of your instance `Assembly` with your controllers & Services, then you can load it either getting it from any included type or like this:

```
var assembly = Assembly.Load("YourApp.NameSace.AssemblyName");
```

Another [nice ref implementation and explanation](https://snede.net/re-use-controllers-views-and-tag-helpers-in-asp-net-core/)

Comment: Has anyone done this in .net6, I can share controllers but Views are not found.