# How to return view from another project in ASP NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, nuget

I have a simple controller method for testing purpose like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Test()
{
    return View("SomeView");
}
```

Assume that I want to create a NuGet package that returns view with name `SomeView`, but this view can be implemented by user of my NuGet package. How can I do this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really asking two separate questions here. One is about accessing views that aren't in the same project as the controller, and a second question about creating a Nuget package.

1. Have a read of [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24344701/706346) to see how to access views in another project.
2. Once you are comfortable with that, then you can turn that other project into a Nuget package. There are loads of articles around explaining how to do that. If you have a specific problem doing that, start a new question here.

Comment: The question you linked to is for ASP.NET 3/4, which is much older than (and very different to) ASP.NET Core, so it won't help the OP. This one is more apt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62817693/what-is-a-best-way-to-share-controler-with-mvc-views-to-another-project

Comment: @Dai Ah, well spotted. Either way, I still feel that there are two completely separate questions here, and that there is plenty of information about how to solve both around.

Comment: I tried solution with `AddApplicationPart` and it seems that it's not working. I created sample projects for testing, one of these has `HomeController` and this is my nuget package. In project where I installed this nuget package I have startup like this: https://pastebin.com/MKJGCcZ1 and instead of exception about that I don't have View, I'm getting 404 not found. What did I wrong?

Comment: Sorry, the problem was something else. This solution with application parts works really fine, but the problem was that I always packed my project as the same version. This made the nuget packages manager was using the old version of the package all the time (even though it was already removed and replaced with another one) despite the package was changed. Thanks for the help!